# precacheAndRoute got error on addToCacheList

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin, sw-precache

I have created PWA and implementef workbox using `workbox-webpack-plugin`.

I got error when i tried to precache the files.

the error that i got (see image below)

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTKIP.png)

```
sw.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: e is not iterable
    at d.addToCacheList (sw.js:1)
    at sw.js:1
    at sw.js:1
    at sw.js:1
```

although `self.__WB_MANIFEST` return correctly

```
0: {revision: "8601238f233fac234d7baf4d32a932d8", url: "favicon.ico"}
10: {revision: "70d6d945809b3a4bde074fb5a8e1a6ac", url: "register.js"}
```

---

I tried debugging `workbox-precaching` but got stuck due to no gulpfile provided.
i cannot find gulpfile on `node_modules/workbox-precaching`.

---

Here the detail of my code
src/sw.js

```
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';

console.log(self.__WB_MANIFEST)
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

webpack.config.js

```
 plugins: [
    ...
    new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
      swSrc: './src/sw.js',
      swDest: 'sw.js',
    })
  ],
```

register.js

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register("sw.js")
            .then(function (registration) {
                console.log(location.href, registration.scope);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            });
    });
```

package.json

```
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.12",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, `InjectManifest` will only replace the first occurrence of `self.__WB_MANIFEST` in your `swSrc` file. Your call to `precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)` will therefore not get the correct replacement, and instead `self.__WB_MANIFEST` (which is `undefined` and not iterable) will be passed to `precacheAndRoute()`.

If you want to do something to the manifest before calling `precacheAndRoute()`, like logging it, then you can do:

```
const manifest = self.__WB_MANIFEST;

// Use manifest however you'd like:
console.log(manifest);
precacheAndRoute(manifest);
```